# What is making the *sources.jar during Maven release?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I am certain that I do not have maven-source-plugin in my  plugins, but a [project-name]-sources.jar is always getting built during release:perform.  It doesn't seem to be doing it during other stages of the build life-cycle.

Unfortunately, this [project-name]-sources.jar gets uploaded to our repository (Nexus).  Management wants all sources to be kept in SVN and away from the repository.

How do I do that?  This is certainly not an assembly issue.  We've tried different build profiles but the [project-name]-sources.jar still remained.  We just don't want any source codes get uploaded to the repository during releases.

Any idea any one?

Thanks in advance.

Below is all we use in the  tag:

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Release Reference: http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/index.html -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <tagBase>http://some.url.here</tagBase>
                <checkModificationExcludes>
                    <checkModificationExclude>.classpath</checkModificationExclude>
                    <checkModificationExclude>.factorypath</checkModificationExclude>
                    <checkModificationExclude>.project</checkModificationExclude>
                    <checkModificationExclude>.rest-shell.log</checkModificationExclude>
                    <checkModificationExclude>.springBeans</checkModificationExclude>
                    <checkModificationExclude>.apt-generated/**</checkModificationExclude>
                    <checkModificationExclude>.settings/**</checkModificationExclude>
                    <checkModificationExclude>src\main\resources\rebel.xml</checkModificationExclude>
                </checkModificationExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin> 
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <index>true</index>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: BTW: You are using very old versions of the plugins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So here is the answer to my own question in case anyone wants to know the work around:

```
    <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      ...
      <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
      ...
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Answer (score 3):

The simply answer is that during the release run the [maven-sources-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-source-plugin/) is attached to the build life cylce (package phase) which is activated by a property `performRelease`. This is defined in the [super-pom which defines this are a profile.](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html)

Here is the appropriate part of the super pom:

```xml
  <profiles>
    <!-- NOTE: The release profile will be removed from future versions of the super POM -->
    <profile>
      <id>release-profile</id>

      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>performRelease</name>
          <value>true</value>
        </property>
      </activation>

      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>attach-sources</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>jar</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>jar</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <updateReleaseInfo>true</updateReleaseInfo>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

Comment: This is precisely the root cause and Maven release plugin documentation says it clearly that "useReleaseProfile" is default to true; hence, it will using the super POM's maven-source-plugin if one doesn't turn it off.  I really appreciate your answer.  Thanks @khmarbaise